# Grep after and before the match

Tags: linux, grep

I want to grep everything after the "system path"  up to before "type =". grep "system path" prints everything after "system path"

Only want to grep from the line - system path="file/aww/ld/lslmux

```
<system path="file/aww/ld/lslmux" type="FILE" reason="filelist" action="NEW" status="COMPLETED"
<system path="file/aww/ld/lslmux/systemfile.xml" type="FILE" reason="filelist" action="NEW" status="COMPLETED"
<system path="file/aww/ld/lslmux/systemfiletest.page" type="FILE" reason="filelist" action="NEW" status="COMPLETED"
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Is it HTML/XML ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot we have our own version of that, no reason to send people to [so], we can send them to https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '<system path="\K[^"]+'  file
file/aww/ld/lslmux
file/aww/ld/lslmux/systemfile.xml
file/aww/ld/lslmux/systemfiletest.page
```

With `Perl`:

```
$ perl -nE 'say for /<system path="\K([^"]+)/g' file
```

#### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what's `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [perlmonks look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of \K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `[^"]+` | any character except `"` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can grep out the first quoted substring on each line by:

```
grep -oP '^([^"]+)"\K[^"]+' input_file
```

Comment: Or `cut -d '"' -f2 < input_file`